# Why the score didn't work properly in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a scoring system based on destroyed balls, so on start, the score is 82, and each ball destroyed should decrease the score by 1.

i made a script for the ball, but the score didn't work properly, can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

**This is the ball script:**

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    private int Count;
    public Text TextCount;

    // Update is called once per frame
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float destroyTimeOut = 2;
    bool hitBase = false;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Count = 82;
        SetTextCount();
    }


    void Update () {
        if(rb.position.y < -3)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Count = Count - 1;
            SetTextCount();

        }
        if (hitBase)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > destroyTimeOut)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                Count = Count - 1;
                SetTextCount();

            }
        }
    }
    float timer;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("base"))
        {
            hitBase = true;
        }
    }

    void SetTextCount()
    {
        TextCount.text = Count.ToString();
    }

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work properly?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean the score decrease to 81 and it didn't change even other balls are destroyed

Comment: I think the problem might be that each ball has its own score.

Comment: Put some logs or use the debugger.

Comment: Every ball has a private int for the count that is set to 82, its not a static int or anything so everytime a ball updates the text it is updating it with its own verision of count, which decremented even if on the next frame its personal private count is 81.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Destroy(gameObject)` this GameObject is destroyed with this `Ball` script that is attached to it.

Separate your score system from the ball collision detection system.

**1**.Create an Empty GameObject and name it "ScoreSystem".

**2**.Create a script and name it "ScoreSys" then use the code below inside it.

**3**.Attach it to the  "ScoreSystem". GameObject.

```
public class ScoreSys : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text TextCount;
    private int _Count;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _Count;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Count != value)
            {
                _Count = value;
                TextCount.text = _Count.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Count = 82;
        TextCount.text = _Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

The score system now has it's own code and GameObject and it won't be destroyed. Also, `Text` is also updated when score changes.

---

Now, you also have to separate the `Ball` script. Simply find the "ScoreSystem" GameObject, get the `ScoreSys` component attached to it and updated the score. The `Ball` script should be attached to the Ball Object that will be destroyed.

Note that I have no idea when the score should update but below is the translation of your current code. You may need to make some changes to get it working properly.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{

    ScoreSys scoreSys;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float destroyTimeOut = 2;
    bool hitBase = false;
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject scoreObj = GameObject.Find("ScoreSystem");
        scoreSys = scoreObj.GetComponent<ScoreSys>();

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (rb.position.y < -3)
        {
            scoreSys.Count--;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (hitBase)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > destroyTimeOut)
            {
                scoreSys.Count--;
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    float timer;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("base"))
        {
            hitBase = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to decide if I should post an answer showing how to use a delegate to do this as well lol.

Comment: @Eddge Delegate is another way to do this but it's not related to the problem which is just the object being destroyed and removing the current score.

Comment: Yea, I know I was just thinking it would cool to show another way to do it without having to connect objects in the editor and using GameObject.find or findObjectsOfType =)

Comment: That makes sense. You don't need my approval to do so.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you make Count a static, then each Ball object will share the same value in memory. As someone else pointed-out, if there are more than one of these Ball objects, they would each have their own idea of the value for Count.

```
    static int Count;
```

Make it static in the class (add one word to your source code) and I think it will act as you desire.

Also, you don't need to explicitly declare 'private' it is the default.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    static int Count;
    public Text TextCount;

    // Update is called once per frame
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float destroyTimeOut = 2;
    bool hitBase = false;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Count = 82;
        SetTextCount();
    }


    void Update () {
        if(rb.position.y < -3)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Count = Count - 1;
            SetTextCount();

        }
        if (hitBase)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > destroyTimeOut)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                Count = Count - 1;
                SetTextCount();

            }
        }
    }
    float timer;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("base"))
        {
            hitBase = true;
        }
    }

    void SetTextCount()
    {
        TextCount.text = Count.ToString();
    }

}
```