# Unity - how to show text for few seconds for each good move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity and programming so I need some help. I am trying to display text for 3sec after player made good move. It's working on first move, text dissapeared but it is still blinking. Probably because it is in update method and this item is still locked... But how can I change this to show this text for 3 seconds after each good move? Only once per item. Thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private GameObject someText
[SerializeField]
private GameObject goodMove;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    someText.SetActive(false);
    goodMove.SetActive(false);
}
void Update()
{
    if (item1.locked && item2.locked && item3.locked)
    {
        someText.SetActive(true);
    }

    if (item1.locked || item2.locked || item3.locked)
    {
        StartCoroutine(waiter());
    }
}
IEnumerator waiter()
{
    goodMove.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    goodMove.SetActive(false);
}
```

}

edit: item is locked when it is dragged to correct place

```
...case TouchPhase.Ended:
            if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - somePlace.position.x) <= 2f &&
            Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - somePlace.position.y) <= 2f)
                    {
                        transform.position = new Vector2(somePlace.position.x, somePlace.position.y);
                        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.4F, 0.4F, 0.4F);
                        locked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        transform.position = new Vector2(initialPosition.x, initialPosition.y);
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: I don;t know what these variables are for, but `if (item1.locked || item2.locked || item3.locked)` does not look correct. If so, though, if you want your text to appear for 3 seconds, why is it not part of your existing 3 second coroutine, or part of a different coroutine?

Comment: @vb381 Draco is right, what youre code is actually doing is to set the text ONLY when the 3 items are locked, and setting the good move when you lock some. I've one more question: when you lock one item and start the 3 seconds goodMove show, if you active another item before the 3 seconds of the first item end, what should happen?

Comment: I added to my question code when it is locked. If I activate another item, nothing will happen I can drag it to correct place, but text shows up only once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's blinking because your're calling `StartCoroutine(waiter());` every frame. You can use boolean variable to make it call once only. If I were you, I would remove the `Update` function and use coroutine to fix it and avoid moving your code in the touch detection script.

Also, the code below is executing every frame:

```
if (item1.locked && item2.locked && item3.locked)
{
    someText.SetActive(true);
}
```

It's better to to create another locked variables so that you can use that to check when the locked variables has changed before doing your `if` statement. Notice the `ItemChanged()` function below, it's doing just that.

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Change YourItemType to whatver your item1, item2, item3 types are
    YourItemType item1, item2, item3;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject someText;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject goodMove;

    bool oldVal1;
    bool oldVal2;
    bool oldVal3;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        someText.SetActive(false);
        goodMove.SetActive(false);

        StartCoroutine(LockChecker());
    }

    IEnumerator LockChecker()
    {
        oldVal1 = item1.locked;
        oldVal2 = item2.locked;
        oldVal3 = item3.locked;

        //Run this code forever as the Update function
        while (true)
        {

            //Check if item has changed
            if (ItemChanged())
            {
                if (item1.locked && item2.locked && item3.locked)
                {
                    someText.SetActive(true);
                }

                if (item1.locked || item2.locked || item3.locked)
                {
                    //Call the waiter function then wait for it to return
                    yield return StartCoroutine(waiter());
                }
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    bool ItemChanged()
    {
        //Check if the booelan variable changed
        if (oldVal1 != item1.locked ||
            oldVal2 != item2.locked ||
            oldVal3 != item3.locked)
        {
            //Update old values
            oldVal1 = item1.locked;
            oldVal2 = item2.locked;
            oldVal3 = item3.locked;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    IEnumerator waiter()
    {
        goodMove.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        goodMove.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Even better, declare your locked variables as properties then use the `get` and `set` assessors to detect when the locked variables changes and start the coroutine. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354735/3785314).

Comment: Thank you very much for great answer. Works great!

also thanks all others for help

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it is probably blinking because once an item is locked, it will continue to be locked, and the Update method will continue to fire your coroutine. Instead, I would put the call to your coroutine right at the point where the item gets locked (and remove the check from your Update of course):

```
        if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - somePlace.position.x) <= 2f &&
        Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - somePlace.position.y) <= 2f)
                {
                    transform.position = new Vector2(somePlace.position.x, somePlace.position.y);
                    transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.4F, 0.4F, 0.4F);
                    locked = true;

                    StartCoroutine(waiter());
                }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I call coroutine waiter from another script?
http://prntscr.com/ljvo5e

Comment: the same way you would normally do it, except inside startcoroutine. ie.`StartCoroutine(myscript.waiter());`